# authenticate всегда возвращает None

Tags: python, django, auth, users, веб-сайт

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse


def auth_check(request):
    try:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        if all([username, password]):
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)

            else:
                return HttpResponse('Неверный логин или пароль!')

    except (KeyError, AttributeError):
        pass

    return redirect('/')
```

Если я активирую функцию с помощью `shell`, то `authenticate` работает корректно и возвращает объект пользователя, а если через сайт, то всегда возвращает `None`. (Делал дебаг, вывел в файл лога то, что ввёл и там всё правильно (`username` и `password`), но `authenticate` возвратил `None`). Как решить проблему?

Comment: Я обнаружил проблему. Почему-то некоторое время после регистрации хостинг pythonanywhere не видит, что пользователь существует и при использовании User.objects.get(username=username) выдаёт ошибку DoesNotExist. Но при получении через shell всё нормально. Что можно придумать тут?

Comment: видимо проверить к какой базе идет подключение в обоих случаях

Comment: как можно проверить?

Comment: добавить логирование в код, в файл где считываются настройки. запустить двумя способами и сравнить вывод.

Comment: Делал, логин и пароль верный, authenticate возвратил None, User.objects.get же DoesNotExist, хотя пользователь есть в бд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как информации недостаточно для того чтобы понять в чем проблема. Я предложу вариант как лучше переписать ваш метод и приэтом добавлю те вещи которые мне кажется могли бы указать на проблему.

```
def auth_check(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    if not (username and password):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Некорректный запрос username и password обязательные поля')
    log.debug(f'database url: {settings.DATABASES}')
    log.debug(f'auth backend: {settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS}')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is None:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('Неверный логин или пароль!')
    
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('/')

@receiver(user_logged_in)
def user_logged_in_callback(sender, request, user, **kwargs):    
    log.debug(f'login user_id={user.id} with username: {user.username}')

@receiver(user_login_failed)
def user_login_failed_callback(sender, credentials, **kwargs):
    log.debug(f'login failed for: {credentials}')
```

Еще на всякий случай бы уточнил какой бэкенд отрабатывает при вызове функции `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`. Добавьте то что получится при выводе в обоих случаях в описание вопроса, чтобы наверняка исключить некоторые глупые варианта, а не просто вам на слово верить. Так как вряд ли баг в джанге. Кстати какая у вас версия? И где хостится база?

PS. для логов лучше завести фековый аккаунт который после удалить сразу, чувствительные вещи можно потереть звездочками