# Django authenticate не работает и возвращает None

Tags: python, django, auth

Вот мой код:

views.py

```
def auth(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        Form = AuthForm(request.POST)

        if Form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            init = Users.objects.get(name=name)

            if init.name == name and init.password == init.hash_password(password):
                request.session['name'] = name

                user = authenticate(request, username=name, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Что то у вас неправильно')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Неправиильный юзернейм или пароль')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Форма заполнена неправильно')
    else:
        Form = AuthForm()
    
    return render(request, 'auth.html', {'Form': Form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

import hashlib
import secrets

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    email = models.TextField(unique=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photos', null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)
    unique_token = models.TextField(null=True)
    password = models.TextField()

    def generate_token(self):
        hash_code = secrets.token_hex(16)

        self.unique_token = hash_code

    def enc_password(self):
        enc_password = hashlib.sha256(bytes(self.password, 'utf-8'))
        self.password = enc_password.hexdigest()
    
    def hash_password(self, argument):
        enc_password = hashlib.sha256(bytes(argument, 'utf-8'))
        enc_password = enc_password.hexdigest()

        return enc_password

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "user_info"
```

Пробовал логгировать и узнать ошибку

```
def auth(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Form = AuthForm(request.POST)

        if Form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = hash_password(request.POST['password'])

            print(f'database url: {settings.DATABASES}')
            print(f'auth backend: {settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS}')
            
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse(user)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'error')
    else:
        Form = AuthForm()
        return render(request, 'auth.html', context={'Form': Form})
```

Вышло:

```
database url: {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': WindowsPath('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python/itforum/itforum/db.sqlite3'), 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': False, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIGRATE': True, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None}}}
auth backend: ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
```

Как вы видите в юзер и пассворд ничего, мне бы хочется узнать почему

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [authenticate всегда возвращает None](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176957/authenticate-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-none)